# fp:precise vs. fp:strict performance

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, floating-point

I detected some differences in my program results between Release and Debug versions. After some research I realized that some floating point optimizations are causing those differences. I have solved the problem by using the fenv_access pragma for disabling some optimizations for some critical methods.

Thinking about it, I realized that it is probably better to use the fp:strict model instead of fp:precise in my program because of its characteristics, but I am worried about performance. I have tried to find some information about the performance issues of fp:strict or the differences in performance between precise and strict, model but I have found very little information.

Does anyone know anything about this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

This happens because you are compiling in 32-bit mode, it uses the x86 floating point processor.  The code optimizer removes redundant moves from the FPU registers to memory and back, leaving intermediary results in the FPU stack.  A pretty important optimization.

Problem is, the FPU stores doubles with 80 bits of precision.  Instead of the 64 bits of precision of a double.  Intel originally assumed this was a feature, producing more accurate intermediary calculations but it is really a bug.  They didn't make the same mistake when they designed the SSE2 instruction set, used by 64 bit compilers to do floating point math.  The XMM registers are 64 bits.

So in the release mode build you get subtly different results since the calculations are performed with more bits.  This should *never* be a problem in a program that uses floating point values to calculate, a double can only store 15 significant digits.  What's different are the noise digits, the ones beyond the first 15 digits.  But sometimes less if your calculation loses significant digits badly.  Like calculating 1 - 3 * (1/3.0).

But yeah, you can use fp:precise to get consistent noise digits.  It forces the intermediate values to be flushed to memory so they cannot remain in the FPU with 80 bits of precision.  It makes your code slow of course.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. As you said I am compiling in 32-bit mode, but I always use fp:precise, is the default in Visual Studio 2008. With this configuration I obtain different results (in my code I compare two values and execute different parts of the code depending on that). Using #pragma fenv_access(on) before the method and #pragma fenv_access(off) after I have solved the problem. Now I am thinking in use fp:strict instead of fp:precise to prevent future errors but I am worried about performance. Do you know if fp:strict performance is significantly lower than fp:precise??

Comment: Nice explanation of the 80-bit vs. 64-bit differen. But,... perhaps nitpicky... does this really answer the question? Or the "implied" question? Alex is mostyl asking about the "performance implications"... and that is precisely the part you do not answer.

Comment: But yes Hans, after reading your post I think that is the root of the problem. I suposse that with optimizations comparation take place between FPU registers, with more precision, and some values that could be considered as equals (with less presision) are considered non equal. Very interesting point, thanks ;)

Comment: 32bit compilers can also use SSE2 to do fp math, if you set `/arch:SSE2` on MSVC, it overrides x87 instructions with SSE2 variants where possible :)

Comment: What I am going to do is to write a test program that performs floating point operations that is said to be optimized under fp:precise and not under fp:strict and then measure performance, is not what I was looking for but is better than nothing. From stuff I have already read probably there is a little difference in performance between precise and strict model. I will post here my results. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: “Intel originally assumed this was a feature, producing more accurate intermediary calculations but it is really a bug. They didn't make the same mistake […]” Sorry, but have got it completely backwards. Intel started work on the 8087 in 1976, recruiting William Kahan as a consultant (http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html ). The 8087 chip was released in 1980. Kahan went on to be instrumental in the standardization of floating-point computations in the IEEE 754 standard. IEEE 754 became official in 1985.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a solution but is what I have :) 
As I have post previously I have wrote a test program that performs floating point operations that is said to be optimized under fp:precise and not under fp:strict and then measure performance. I run it 10000 times and, in average, fp:strict is 2.85% slower than fp:precise.

Answer (score 1):

Just offering my two cents:

I have an image processing program that autovectorizes, the aim was to compare the performance and accuracy taking matlab as a gold standard.

Using VS2012 and an Intel i950.

Critical region error & runtime

```
2.3328196e-02 465 ms with strict 
7.1277611e-02 182 ms with precise
7.1277611e-02 188 ms with fast
```

strict did not vecotrization

Using strict slowed the code down by 2x. Which was not acceptable.

Answer (score -5):

It's absolutely normal to see performance difference between a Debug and Release version.

The compiler and run-times will do a lot more additional sanity checks in debug version; don't compare one to the other, especially in regards to performance; compare release vs. release with different compiler switches.

On the other hand, if the results are different between the 2 versions, then you will have to go in and check for programming errors (most probably).

Max.

Comment: he already found the error (precise vs strict floating point calculation) and is worried about that in either build modes.

Comment: As you said, Debug and release performance aren´t comparable. And I don´t want to compare this. On the other hand, I had differents results between debug and release versions. Now I had solved this. My doubt is because probably is better to use fp:strict as floating point model for my program. So What I am looking for is some kind of analysis or general overview of the performance issues of the fp:strict model and its differences with fp:precise.

Comment: @Alex you should have just done some profiling with your concrete calculations. For each code performance will vary greatly. You could compare time it take to execute in different modes and then decide if `strict` is worth it.